# How to update SQL DB after Android App purchase with google pay

Tags: android, google-play, in-app-purchase, google-pay, in-app-subscription

I currently have a subscription based website that takes Payments via Paypal and then my sql DB is updated using IPN messaged from Paypal using php script. I am now creating a android app of the site and will be adding in app billing for it. Wondering if google pay have any similar IPN service like paypal so so that I can update my DB. (I have done a fair bit of research but cannot find an answer)

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

PayPal has a Android SDK for payments. Details here : https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/paypal-here/sdk-dev/native/

You will get callbacks regarding payment process from which you will be able to call your apis and update the database.

You could also look into Google billing. That is when the user uses their Google play account to pay. If user has linked their PayPal or other payment gateway  to their Google play, then that can also be used.